# multiple image upload is not working in iphone and ipad

Tags: php, iphone, ipad, file-upload

I am trying to use upload images it works perfect in browser but it doesn't work in iphone and ipad .below are code and screenshots for iphone

```
test.php
---------
<?php 
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        //echo "<pre>";
        //print_r($_FILES);
        //exit;
        copy($_FILES["image1"]["tmp_name"],"upload/".$_FILES["image1"]["name"]);
        copy($_FILES["image2"]["tmp_name"],"upload/".$_FILES["image2"]["name"]);
        copy($_FILES["image3"]["tmp_name"],"upload/".$_FILES["image3"]["name"]);
        echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["image1"]["name"];
        echo "<br>";
        echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["image2"]["name"];
        echo "<br>";
        echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["image3"]["name"];
    }
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>demo</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
         image 1 : <input type="file" name="image1" ><br/>
         image 2 : <input type="file" name="image2" ><br/>
         image 3 : <input type="file" name="image3" ><br/>
         <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

### iphone screenshot

As we can see from this below array this is displayed in iphone/ipad the image names are same for all and when i try to check for upload folder it displayed only the last image i.e third image .

```
[image1] => Array
    (
        [name] => image.jpg
        [type] => image/jpeg
        [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpewhdwx
        [error] => 0
        [size] => 44009
    )

[image2] => Array
    (
        [name] => image.jpg
        [type] => image/jpeg
        [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpwYDYBM
        [error] => 0
        [size] => 27762
    )

[image3] => Array
    (
        [name] => image.jpg
        [type] => image/jpeg
        [tmp_name] => /tmp/php0vqnB2
        [error] => 0
        [size] => 32961
    )
```

Comment: I wonder how it works on browser. If all 3 images have same names, then it will overwrite each other leaving only one image in upload folder

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.Yes the array that i have displayed are of iphone screenshot but if we use print_r() and check it in browser its different name and its fine. the issue is only in ipad and iphone.please help :)

Comment: Are you selecting same image for all three fields?

Comment: I believe in browser you are selecting 3 different images for each input field, but on iDevices you are selecting the same image

Comment: no all images are different and their names are also different in iphone and ipad

Comment: Looks like Safari on iOs < 6 does not support multiple file upload. This page (http://www.mobilexweb.com/blog/iphone-5-ios-6-html5-developers) shows a way to use <input type="file" multiple>, but not sure how php will get the array. may be you have to use name as name[]

Comment: yes i have used with name[] and the result is the same .if i try for multiple file at a time will it work ?

Comment: Thats what the page says, you have to put <input name="name[]" type="file" multiple> and then select multiple files

Comment: i have used <input name="name[]" type="file" multiple> but result is the same

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok i have found the solution :)

we have issue in ipad's and iphone's as they use name for all images as image.jpg so if we use multiple image this gets overridden so we need to add rand() or any unique key to the name at time of copy to folder.

```
$image1 = rand().$_FILES["image1"]["name"];
    $image2 = rand().$_FILES["image2"]["name"];
    $image3 = rand().$_FILES["image3"]["name"];

    copy($_FILES["image1"]["tmp_name"],"upload/".$image1);
    copy($_FILES["image2"]["tmp_name"],"upload/".$image2);
    copy($_FILES["image3"]["tmp_name"],"upload/".$image3);
```

Comment: While **extremely** unlikely, `rand()` could return the same value twice.  Check for that.

Comment: @mbmast help me.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60221133/php-codeigniter-image-uploading-working-properly-in-all-devices-but-on-workin?noredirect=1#comment106518826_60221133