# IOS device issue with Html form element names

Tags: html, ios

I have simple html-form with four file fields and every field has unique name.

```
<form method="post" action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="upload_target" onsubmit="return validateform(this);" >
<input type="file" name="uploaded_file1" id="uploaded_file1" onchange="changefilestate('1');" />   
<input type="file" name="uploaded_file2" id="uploaded_file2" onchange="changefilestate('2');" />   
<input type="file" name="uploaded_file3" id="uploaded_file3" onchange="changefilestate('3');" />   
<input type="file" name="uploaded_file4" id="uploaded_file4" onchange="changefilestate('4');" />
```

Files are combined on server in one file with Imagick. 
This is working fine in desktop and mobile browsers but with IPhone (using whatever browser) fields get renamed (or something) during submit because every time combined file contains only first uploaded file in three times (if three files were submitted). That is why i think IOS browser somehow screw up the field names.

Update: Maybe problem is not in form processing at all but in IPhone filemanager which does not change the file when field is changed and a new file is selected. I don't have IPhone in reach so i can't test it.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.
It was device related problem because every images get always same name (image.jpg).

Similar issue: [multiple image upload is not working in iphone and ipad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22189552/multiple-image-upload-is-not-working-in-iphone-and-ipad)